# Passing variables from view to controller (MVC)

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my view i have a foreach statement which grabs all the nessesary data from the database which displays correctly.

Here is the view:

```
<?php

?>

    <div class="cmt-container" >
        <?php

        foreach($results as $row){
            $user = $row->user;
            $comment = $row->comment;
            $date = $row->date;
            $name = $row->name;
            $joke = $row->joke;
            $joke_id = $row->joke_id;

            // Get gravatar Image
            // https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
            $default = "mm";
            $size = 35;
            $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/"."?d=".$default."&s=".$size;

            ?>

            <div class="cmt-cnt">
                <img src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" />
                <div class="thecom">
                    <h5><?php echo $user; ?></h5><span data-utime="1371248446" class="com-dt"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
                    <br/>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $comment; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->


        <?php

        }
        ?>

<?php

echo form_open('comments/insertComment');

?>
        <div class="new-com-bt">
            <span>Write a comment ...</span>
        </div>

        <div class="new-com-cnt">
            <input type="text" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Name is optional" />
            <textarea class="the-new-com" id="the-new-com" name="the-new-com" placeholder="Write your comment here..."></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="joke_id">
            <input class="bt-add-com" type="submit" value="Post comment">
            <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- end of comments container "cmt-container" -->

<?php

echo form_close();

?>
```

My question is, how can i pass the $joke_id variable to the insertComment function in my comments controller.

I have put the input field as hidden on the joke_id field because i want to assign the ID of a joke to a comment, so the joke will have unique comments.

Comment: you can post `form` to `Controller` action.. but `$joke_id` would be multiple then you should use array type name `joke_id[]` in form hidden element

Comment: Assuming that `$results` are being filtered by `$joke_id` in your controller, simply pass `$joke_id` to the view the same way that the `$results` are being sent.

Comment: No I have already got that. I want to be able pass the result of the $joke_id to a function in my controller

Comment: Your stated problem aside, you are closing `cmt-container` before you close your form, resulting in incorrect html. You should move that div closure to after `<?php echo form_close(); ?>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the comments are on the same page as the joke, you can just take the $joke_id and put it in the hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="joke_id" value="<?php echo $joke_id; ?>">
```

And when you add a comment (I assume you handle the form datas in the insertComment() function), you can access the joke id by $_POST['joke_id'].
(yes, that's not really secure but if your user can comment any joke, you just have to check that a joke with the id equal to $_POST['joke_id'] exists in the DB and if so, you just insert the comment)

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<?php echo form_open('comments/insertComment'); ?>
        <div class="new-com-bt">
            <span>Write a comment ...</span>
        </div>

        <div class="new-com-cnt">
            <input type="text" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Name is optional" />
            <textarea class="the-new-com" id="the-new-com" name="the-new-com" placeholder="Write your comment here..."></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="jokeid" value="<?= $joke_id; ?>">
            <input class="bt-add-com" type="submit" value="Post comment">
            <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- end of comments container "cmt-container" -->

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

and in your insert comment controller

```
    public function __construct() {
    //codes here
    $joke_id = $this->input->post('jokeid'); 
}
```